# Do not wish for something more than you work for

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, grammaticality, ellipsis

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

- "Do not wish for something more than you work for."

I'm pretty sure that the following separate sentences are correct, but it somehow sounds somewhat weird when put together:

- Do not wish for something.
- Owning a house is something to work for.

I think that I'm confused because you can stress "Do not wish for something more" while you should stress "Do not wish for something" and "more than you work for".

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! Please note that we are no proofreading service. If you have a *specific* question why you think there might be an error or room for improvement, feel free to edit your question. For advice on good questions, see the help center on top of every page or here: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain a little more about what seems strange to you. I don't think "Something to work for" is a complete sentence. The only verb in it is part of the phrase describing "something". "Owning a house is something to work for." would be an example of a complete sentence.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're missing a word:

"Do not wish for something more than you work for it."

The issue here is that "wish for something" and "work for (it)" are essentially independent clauses, and the "for" after "work" has to refer to something in the same clause.

(Some people will tell you you can't finish a sentence with a preposition, but this is not true.  However, the preposition does have to point to a noun or phrase *somewhere*.)

Comment: I'm not certain you need the "it". "Don't wish for something more" could mean "Don't wish for more than that which you have earned through work." as opposed to "Don't spend more time wishing for something than working for it." The sentence is somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Maybe it should be: "Don't wish for something more than you work for it." or "Don't wish for something more, more than you work for."

Anyway. Thanks! Going to use the sentence with the "it".

Comment: "Do not wish for something (which is) more than that for which you work."  That's the strict version.